# Conditional Probability not giving desired result

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So I am not getting the given solutions to this problem and I would appreciate some feedback on where the errors are.

On any given day, the probability that Tomas works on his poetry is $0.55$, and the probability that he stops at his local pub is $0.75$. Given that he does at least one of those two things, find the probability that on any given day Tomas:

(i) Goes to the pub and works on his poetry

(ii) Goes to the pub but does not work on his poetry

So first I defined both events. Keeping in mind that this is conditional probability as he is given to do at least one of these two events.

Let $X$ be the event Tomas goes to the pub and let $Y$ be the event Tomas works on his poetry. He always does at least one of these two which is $P(\text{At least 1}) = 1 - P(\text{None}) = 1 - 0.25\times0.45=0.8875$.

Question (i) is essentially asking for
\begin{align}
P(X \text{ AND } Y | \text{ At least 1 }) &= \frac{P(\text{ At least 1 } | X \text{ AND } Y)P(X \text{ AND } Y)}{P(\text{ At least 1)}}\\
 &= \frac{1\times(0.75\times0.55)}{0.8875}\\
 &= 0.46478 \ldots  
\end{align}

This does not match the provided solution of $0.3$

Similarly for Question (ii)

\begin{align}
P(X \text{ AND } Y' | \text{ At least 1 }) &= \frac{P(\text{ At least 1 } | X \text{ AND } Y')P(X \text{ AND } Y')}{P(\text{ At least 1)}}\\
 &= \frac{(0.75 \times 0.45)\times(0.75 \times 0.45)}{0.8875}\\
 &= 0.12834\ldots
\end{align}

Which does not match the given solution of $0.45$.

Is there a flaw in my thinking or are the provided solutions incorrect?

Comment: I think part (i) is $P(X\cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X\cap Y)$.

Comment: @peterwhy due to the "Given that he does at least one of those two things" why do we not use Beyes Theorem?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer the question.  A priori we could have $P(both)$ any value between $.3$ and $.55$

Comment: @lulu $P(both) = P(X) \times P(Y) = 0.75 \times 0.55 = 0.4125$ surely ?

Comment: @Kendall only if they are independent.  Perhaps Tomas is less likely to work on poetry when in the pub drinking than other days (distracted), or perhaps more likely (inspired).

Comment: Recall that $\Pr(X\cap Y) = \Pr(X)\times \Pr(Y)$ if *and only if* they are independent events.  When they are not independent events, $\Pr(X\cap Y)$ is *not equal to* $\Pr(X)\times \Pr(Y)$.  Unless stated otherwise, you should always be skeptical of things being independent.  You may make the assumption that they are independent, but that would require you to have made the assumption which although allows you to continue the problem puts a big disclaimer that the answer you arrive at is flawed and can not be fully trusted.

Comment: @JMoravitz Tricky advice, which I agree with; skepticism is certainly advisable.  However, based on the Probability problems that have been presented at MathSE, it is reasonable to assume that a fair percentage of them appear to be poorly written because the problem composer wrote poorly.  Then, the problem solver has to try to infer the educational value of the problem, based on the solver's educational background,  and try to infer the problem composer's (often unclear) intent.  Then, the problem solver has to question what assumptions are necessary in order to make the problem workable.

Comment: @lulu Hash is where you find it.  See my answer.

Comment: @Henry I think they should be independent. I can easily replace this problem with Tomas flipping 2 biased coins each day. The coin biased to heads with a probability of 0.75 is the same as going to the pub and the second coin biased to heads with prob 0.55 is the same as writing poetry. Each day he flips both coins and the 4 outcomes HH, HT, TH, and HH correspond to going to neither, going to the pub only, writing poetry only, or both respectively . There is no ways these 2 events are dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the comments, let me first say that I originally answered part (1) in the same way that the OP (i.e. original poster) did.

That is, I assumed that the events of going to the pub and working on poetry were independent events, which led me to the conclusion that the desired probability is

$$ \frac{(0.55) \times (0.75)}{1 - [(0.45)(0.25)]} \approx 0.4648. \tag1 $$

When I then read that the given solution to part (1) was (instead) $(0.3)$ the challenge of part (1) changed.  Now, I had to accept that the problem was poorly written and had to reverse engineer some way of interpreting the *hash* so as to reach the computation of $(0.3).$

---

What you have to do is to assume that Tomas always either writes poetry or goes to the pub or both, every day.  You then have to assume that **simultaneously**, his probability of writing poetry and going to the pub are

$(0.55), (0.75)$ respectively.

Let $E_1$ denote the event of writing poetry.
Let $E_2$ denote the event of going to the pub.

What you then have to conclude is that since 
$(1.00) = P(E_1 \cup E_2) = p(E_1) + p(E_2) - p(E_1 \cap E_2)$ 
$= (0.55) + (0.75) - p(E_1 \cap E_2)$,

that you must have that $p(E_1 \cap E_2) = (0.3).$

---

Then, part (2) becomes $p(E_2) - p(E_1 \cap E_2)$

$= (0.75 - 0.3) = (0.45).$

---

Not all people knowledgeable in Math should write Math books.

Comment: Hold on, so the provided solution assumes that these 2 events are dependent? Oh gosh. I see the argument now to get to the given solutions. I agree the question is poorly written. To be honest I think our original interpretation of this problem is the better one. Thank you for your time :)